# Which Adobe product must I use to create a moving banner like this?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, advertising

I want to create a moving banner just like this:
http://share.bannersnack.com/FB8FFFBC5A8/bc561lfno

I need to make it in a GIF format. Which Adobe product do I need?

Comment: There's actually a couple products you can use... Personally I use Photoshop for gifs but that's just because I know it best.

Answer (score 1):

**That is not an image alone.**

That is a web page, using **javascript** to move and change separate elements. The clock in the middle is the only image, and it's independent of the other elements. Nothing there is actually a self-contained animated image.

[image]

That being posted, you *could* create an animated image which is similar.

Most would use **Photoshop** if they wanted this as a single animated gif. But really there are a ton of applications out there capable of making animated gif files. I believe After Effect and Premier from Adobe can also create animated gifs. Or you could use anything and export an image sequence then piece it together for animation using Photoshop.